# How to get secrets from Vault into K8s without saving them as secrets

Tags: docker, kubernetes, vault

How can I inject secrets from Vault into K8s, e.g. to pull from a private registry, without storing them as secrets in K8s itself?

Comment: Please search for similar questions first. I found several duplicate questions. For example [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61239479/injecting-vault-secrets-into-kubernetes-pod-environment-variable) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52859115/hashicorp-vault-to-populate-kubernetes-secrets).

Comment: Kindly review the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as it can assist you in structuring your inquiry more effectively, increasing the likelihood of obtaining the desired answer. Additionally, providing details about your attempts or any preliminary ideas you may have can contribute to a more comprehensive response.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Injecting vault secrets into Kubernetes Pod Environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61239479/injecting-vault-secrets-into-kubernetes-pod-environment-variable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do this in combination with Vault, besides the [solution provided by the K8s documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/):

- [Vault Secrets Operator for Kubernetes](https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/tutorials/kubernetes/vault-secrets-operator)
- [vault-k8s](https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/docs/platform/k8s)
- [vault-csi-provider](https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/docs/platform/k8s/csi)

Additionally, there is also an [ArgoCD plugin](https://argocd-vault-plugin.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage/#simple) that might be useful.

I linked the respective documentation where you can find more detailed information and tutorials, also here is an [overview](https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/tutorials/kubernetes).

Comment: I'm sorry, but I haven't succeeded yet. I'm trying to pull from the repository, but the token from valt is still not being read. Is there an example with a solution to a similar problem?

Comment: The first link isn't related to Vault